# How to represent kWh usage by year against average temperature?

Tags: data-visualization

Just for fun, I want to chart my monthly household power consumption year-over-year.  However, I wish to include some reference to monthly temperature so I can determine if my home or behavior is improving, worsening, or holding steady in regards to kWh usage.

The data I am working with:

```
+----------+--------+-----------+----------------+----------+-----------+------------+
|  Month   | # Days | kWh Usage | Daily kWh Avg. | Avg. Low | Avg. High | Avg. Temp. |
+----------+--------+-----------+----------------+----------+-----------+------------+
| Mar 2015 |     32 |      1048 |             33 |       40 |        60 |         50 |
| Feb 2015 |     29 |      1156 |             40 |       32 |        54 |         43 |
| Jan 2015 |     33 |      1143 |             35 |       38 |        57 |         47 |
| Dec 2014 |     30 |       887 |             30 |       39 |        61 |         50 |
| Nov 2014 |     29 |       645 |             22 |       45 |        67 |         56 |
| Oct 2014 |     29 |       598 |             21 |       60 |        78 |         69 |
| Sep 2014 |     32 |       893 |             28 |       70 |        85 |         77 |
| Aug 2014 |     30 |       965 |             32 |       72 |        87 |         79 |
| Jul 2014 |     29 |       784 |             27 |       72 |        87 |         79 |
| Jun 2014 |     32 |      1018 |             32 |       69 |        87 |         78 |
| May 2014 |     30 |       702 |             23 |       63 |        82 |         72 |
| Apr 2014 |     33 |       722 |             22 |       50 |        71 |         60 |
| Mar 2014 |     29 |       830 |             29 |       41 |        62 |         52 |
| Feb 2014 |     28 |      1197 |             43 |       32 |        52 |         42 |
| Jan 2014 |     33 |      1100 |             33 |       38 |        59 |         49 |
| Dec 2013 |     30 |       856 |             29 |       40 |        63 |         51 |
| Nov 2013 |     33 |       686 |             21 |       48 |        70 |         59 |
| Oct 2013 |     30 |       527 |             18 |       61 |        77 |         69 |
| Sep 2013 |     30 |       817 |             27 |       69 |        86 |         77 |
| Aug 2013 |     28 |       991 |             35 |       72 |        86 |         79 |
| Jul 2013 |     31 |       993 |             32 |       73 |        86 |         79 |
| Jun 2013 |     30 |       847 |             28 |       66 |        83 |         74 |
| May 2013 |     29 |       605 |             21 |       59 |        76 |         67 |
| Apr 2013 |     34 |       791 |             23 |       47 |        66 |         57 |
+----------+--------+-----------+----------------+----------+-----------+------------+
```

I started with a column chart easily comparing month-to-month values:

[image: Month-to-Month Usage Column Chart]

I envisioned a nice background area or line graph mapped to a secondary (right) vertical axis showing the high/low ranges but realized that would be problematic with the multi-year groupings.

It would be easy with one single year:

[image: 2014 kWh Usage with Temperatures]

**I am curious to know if anyone can recommend a way of combining all the yearly data into a single chart with temperature comparisons?**

Is there some ratio I could use that could effectively relate the kWh usage to average temperature... or some other display technique I am overlooking... or am I stuck with one chart per year?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would like to suggest that **the important thing is to develop a *physically realistic, practically useful* model of energy cost.**  That will work better to detect changes in costs than any visualization of the raw data can accomplish.  By comparing this to [the solution offered on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29778991), we have a very nice case study in the difference between *fitting a curve to data* and *performing a meaningful statistical analysis.*

(This suggestion is based on having fit such a model to my own household usage a decade ago and applying it to track changes during that period.  Note that once the model is fit, it can easily be calculated in a spreadsheet for the purpose of tracking changes, so we should not feel limited by the (in)capabilities of spreadsheet software.)

For these data, **such a physically plausible model produces a substantially different picture of energy costs and usage patterns than a simple alternative model** (a quadratic least-squares fit of daily usage against monthly mean temperature).  Consequently, the simpler model cannot be considered a reliable tool for understanding, predicting, or comparing energy use patterns.

---

#### Analysis

[Newton's Law of Cooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convective_heat_transfer#Newton.27s_law_of_cooling) says that, to a good approximation, the cost of heating (during a unit of time) should be directly proportional to the difference between the outside temperature $t$ and the inside temperature $t_0$.  Let that constant of proportionality be $-\alpha$. The cost of cooling also should be proportional to that temperature difference, with a similar--but not necessarily identical--constant of proportionality $\beta$.  (Each of these is determined by the insulating capability of the house as well as the efficiencies of the heating and cooling systems.)

**Estimating $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (which are expressed as kilowatts (or dollars) per degree per unit time) are among the most important things that can be accomplished,** because they enable us to *predict* future costs, as well as measure the efficiencies of the house and its energy systems.

Because these data are total electricity usage, they include non-heating costs such as lighting, cooking, computing, and entertainment.  **Also of interest is an estimate of this average base energy usage** (per unit time), which I will call $\gamma$: it provides a floor on how much energy can be saved and enables predictions of future costs when efficiency improvements of known magnitude are made.  (For instance, after four years I replaced a furnace by one claimed to be 30% more efficient--and indeed it was exactly that.)

Finally, as a (gross) approximation I will assume the house is maintained at a nearly constant temperature $t_0$ throughout the year.  (In my personal model I assume two temperatures, $t_0 \le t_1$, for winter and summer respectively--but there aren't yet enough data in this example to estimate both of them reliably and they would be pretty close anyway.)  Knowing this value helps one evaluate the consequences of maintaining the house at a slightly different temperature, which is one important energy-saving option.

**The data present a singularly important and interesting complication**: they reflect *total* costs during periods when outside temperatures fluctuate--and they fluctuate a lot, usually about one-quarter of their annual range each month.  As we will see, this creates a substantial difference between the correct underlying *instantaneous* model just described and the values of the monthly totals.  The effect is especially pronounced in the in-between months, where both (or neither) heating and cooling take place.  Any model that does not account for this variation would mistakenly "think" energy costs should be at the base rate $\gamma$ during any month with an average temperature of $t_0$, but the reality is far different.

We don't (readily) have detailed information about the monthly temperature fluctuations apart from their ranges.  I propose handling that with an approach that is practical, but a tiny bit inconsistent.  Except at the extreme temperatures, each month will usually experience gradual increases or decreases in temperature.  This means we can take the distribution to be approximately uniform.  When the range of a uniform variable has length $L$, that variable has a standard deviation of $s = L/\sqrt{6}$.  I use this relationship to convert the ranges (from `Avg. Low` to `Avg. High`) to standard deviations.  But then, essentially to obtain a nicely behaved model, I will downweight the variation at the ends of these ranges by using *Normal* distributions (with these estimated SDs and means given by `Avg. Temp`).

Finally, **we must standardize the data to a common unit time.**  Although that's already present in the `Daily kWh Avg.` variable, it lacks precision, so let's instead divide the total by the number of days in order to gain back the lost precision.

Thus, the model of unit-time cooling costs $Y$ at an outdoor temperature of $t$ is

$$y(t) = \gamma + \alpha(t-t_0)I(t\lt t_0) + \beta(t-t_0)I(t\gt t_0) + \varepsilon(t)$$

where $I$ is the indicator function and $\varepsilon$ represents everything not otherwise explicitly captured in this model.  It has four parameters to estimate: $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, and $t_0$.  (If you're really sure of $t_0$ you could fix its value rather than estimating it.)

The *reported* total costs during a time period $x_0$ to $x_1$ when the temperature $t(x)$ varies with time $x$ will therefore be

$$\eqalign{
&\text{Cost}(x_0,x_1) = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} y(t)dt \\ 
&=\int_{x_0}^{x_1} \left(\gamma + \alpha(t(x)-t_0)I(t(x)\lt t_0) + \beta(t(x)-t_0)I(t(x)\gt t_0) + \varepsilon(t(x))\right) t^\prime(x) dx.
}$$

If the model is any good at all, the fluctuations in $\varepsilon(t)$ ought to average to a value $\bar\varepsilon$ close to zero and will appear to randomly change month to month.  Approximating the fluctuations in $t(x)$ with a Normal distribution of mean $\bar{t}$ (the monthly average) and standard deviation $s(\bar t)$ (as previously given from the monthly range) and doing the integrals yields

$$\bar{y}(\bar{t}) = \gamma + (\beta-\alpha)s(\bar t)^2 \phi_s(\bar t-t_0) + (\bar{t}-t_0)\left(\beta + (\alpha-\beta)\Phi_s(t_0 - \bar{t})\right) + \bar\varepsilon(\bar{t}).$$

In this formula, $\Phi_s$ is the cumulative distribution of a Normal variate of zero mean and standard deviation $s(\bar t)$; $\phi$ is its density.

---

#### Model fitting

This model, although expressing a nonlinear relationship between costs and temperature, is nevertheless linear in the variables $\alpha,\beta,$ and $\gamma$.  However, since it is nonlinear in $t_0$, and $t_0$ is not known, we need a nonlinear fitting procedure.  To illustrate, I simply dumped it into a likelihood maximizer (using `R` for the computation), assuming the $\bar\varepsilon$ are independent and identically distributed, with normal distributions of mean zero and common standard deviation $\sigma$.

For these data, the estimates are

$$(\hat\alpha,\hat\beta,\hat\gamma,\hat {t_0}, \hat\sigma) = (-1.489, 1.371, 10.2, 63.4, 1.80).$$

This means:

- The cost to heat is approximately $1.49$ kWh/day/degree F.
- The cost to cool is approximately $1.37$ kWh/day/degree F.  Cooling is a little more efficient.
- The base (non-heating/cooling) energy usage is $10.2$ kWh/day.  (This number is fairly uncertain; additional data will help pin it down better.)
- The house is maintained at a temperature near $63.4$ degrees F.
- The other variations not explicitly accounted for in the model have a standard deviation of $1.80$ kWh/day.

Confidence intervals and other quantitative expressions of uncertainty in these estimates can be obtained in standard ways with the maximum likelihood machinery.

---

#### Visualization

To illustrate this model, the following figure plots the data, the underlying model, the fit to the monthly averages, and a simple least-squares quadratic fit.

[image: Figure]

The monthly data are shown as dark crosses.  The horizontal gray lines on which they lie show the monthly temperature ranges.  Our underlying model, reflecting Newton's law, is shown by the red and blue line segments meeting at a temperature of $t_0$.  *Our fit to the data is not a curve*, because it depends on the temperature ranges.  It is shown therefore as individual solid blue and red points.  (Nevertheless, because the monthly ranges do not vary a lot, these points do seem to trace out a curve--almost the same as the dashed quadratic curve.)  Finally, the dashed curve is the quadratic least squares fit (to the dark crosses).

Notice how much the fits depart from the underlying (instantaneous) model, especially in the middle temperatures!  This is the effect of monthly averaging.  (Think of the heights of the red and blue lines being "smeared" across each horizontal gray segment.  At extreme temperatures everything is centered at the lines, but at middle temperatures the two sides of the "V" get averaged together, reflecting the need for heating at some times and cooling at other times during the month.)

---

#### Model comparison

The two fits--the one painstakingly developed here and the simple, easy, quadratic fit--agree closely both with each other and with the data points.  The quadratic fit is not quite as good, but it's still decent: its adjusted mean residual (for three parameters) is $2.07$ kWh/day, whereas the adjusted mean residual of the Newton's law model (for four parameters) is $1.97$ kWh/day, about 5% lower.  *If all you want to do is plot a curve through the data points, then the simplicity and relative fidelity of the quadratic fit would recommend it.*

However, the quadratic fit is utterly useless for learning what's going on!  Its formula,

$$\bar y(\bar t) = 219.95 - 6.241 \bar t + 0.04879 (\bar t)^2,$$

reveals nothing of use directly.  In all fairness, we could analyze it a little:

1. This is a parabola with vertex at $\hat t_0 = 6.241/(2\times 0.04879) = 64.0$ degrees F.  We could take this as an estimate of the constant house temperature.  It does not differ significantly from our first estimate of $63.4$ degrees.  However, the predicted cost at this temperature is $219.95 - 6.241(63.4) + 0.04879(63.4)^2 = 20.4$ kWh/day.  *This is twice the base energy usage* fit with Newton's Law.
2. The marginal cost of heating or cooling is obtained from the absolute value of the derivative,  $\bar{y}^\prime(\bar t) = -6.241 + 2(0.04879)\bar{t}$.  For example, using this formula we would estimate the cost of heating a house when the outside temperature is $90$ degrees as $-6.241 + 2(0.04879)(90) = 2.54$ kWh/day/degree F.  *This is twice the value estimated with Newton's Law*.

   Similarly, the cost to heat the house at an outdoor temperature of $32$ degrees would be estimated as $|-6.241 + 2(0.04879)(32)| = 3.12$ kWh/day/degree F.  *This is more than twice the value estimated with Newton's Law.*

   At the middle temperatures, the quadratic fit errs in the other direction.  Indeed, at its vertex in the $60$ to $68$ degree range it predicts *nearly zero marginal heating or cooling costs,* even though this *mean* temperature comprises days as cool as $50$ degrees and as warm as $78$ degrees.  (Few people reading this post will still have their heat off at $50$ degrees (=$10$ degrees C)!)

In brief, although it *looks* almost as good in the visualization, **the quadratic fit grossly errs in estimating fundamental quantities of interest related to energy usage.**  Its use for evaluating changes in usage is therefore problematic and should be discouraged.

---

#### Computation

This `R` code performed all the computing and plotting.  It can readily be adapted to similar datasets.

```R
#
# Read and process the raw data.
#
x <- read.csv("F:/temp/energy.csv")
x$Daily <- x$Usage / x$Length
x <- x[order(x$Temp), ]
#pairs(x)
#
# Fit a quadratic curve.
#
fit.quadratic <- lm(Daily ~ Temp+I(Temp^2), data=x)
# par(mfrow=c(2,2))
# plot(fit.quadratic)
# par(mfrow=c(1,1))
#
# Fit a simple but realistic heating-cooling model with maximum likelihood.
#
response <- function(theta, x, s) {
  alpha <- theta[1]; beta <- theta[2]; gamma <- theta[3]; t.0 <- theta[4]
  x <- x - t.0
  gamma + (beta-alpha)*s^2*dnorm(x, 0, s) +  x*(beta + (alpha-beta)*pnorm(-x, 0, s))
}
log.L <- function(theta, y, x, s) {
  #   theta = (alpha, beta, gamma, t.0, sigma)
  #   x = time
  #   s = estimated SD
  #   y = response
  y.hat <- response(theta, x, s)
  sigma <- theta[5]
  sum((((y - y.hat) / sigma) ^2 + log(2 * pi * sigma^2))/2)
}
theta <- c(alpha=-1, beta=5/4, gamma=20, t.0=65, sigma=2) # Initial guess
x$Spread <- (x$Temp.high - x$Temp.low)/sqrt(6)            # Uniform estimate
fit <- nlm(log.L, theta, y=x$Daily, x=x$Temp, x$Spread)
names(fit$estimate) <- names(theta)
#$
# Set up for plotting.
#
i.pad <- 10
plot(range(x$Temp)+c(-i.pad,i.pad), c(0, max(x$Daily)+20), type="n", 
     xlab="Temp", ylab="Cost, kWh/day",
     main="Data, Model, and Fits")
#
# Plot the data.
#
l <- matrix(mapply(function(l,r,h) {c(l,h,r,h,NA,NA)}, 
                   x$Temp.low, x$Temp.high, x$Daily), 2)
lines(l[1,], l[2,], col="Gray")
points(x$Temp, x$Daily, type="p", pch=3)
#
# Draw the models.
#
x0 <- seq(min(x$Temp)-i.pad, max(x$Temp)+i.pad, length.out=401)
lines(x0, cbind(1, x0, x0^2) %*% coef(fit.quadratic), lwd=3, lty=3)
#curve(response(fit$estimate, x, 0), add=TRUE, lwd=2, lty=1)
t.0 <- fit$estimate["t.0"]
alpha <- fit$estimate["alpha"]
beta <- fit$estimate["beta"]
gamma <- fit$estimate["gamma"]
cool <- "#1020c0"; heat <- "#c02010"
lines(c(t.0, 0), gamma + c(0, -alpha*t.0), lwd=2, lty=1, col=cool)
lines(c(t.0, 100), gamma + c(0, beta*(100-t.0)), lwd=2, lty=1, col=heat)
#
# Display the fit.
#
pred <- response(fit$estimate, x$Temp, x$Spread)
points(x$Temp, pred, pch=16, cex=1, col=ifelse(x$Temp < t.0, cool, heat))
#lines(lowess(x$Temp, pred, f=1/4))
#
# Estimate the residual standard deviations.
#
residuals <- x$Daily - pred
sqrt(sum(residuals^2) / (length(residuals) - 4))
sqrt(sum(resid(fit.quadratic)^2) / (length(residuals) - 3))
```

Comment: This may be the single best response to any stack overflow question I have read.  I greatly appreciate the time taken to explain the logic and reasoning behind the solution.

Comment: Physics is more hairy than this.  The condenser and evaporator switch roles in heating vs. cooling.  This means they act like two different systems, not one continuous.  Heating degree days, cooling degree days, and dehumidification degree days are three separarate cost-drivers, and depending on geographic location (think ak, wi, ca, az, mo, and fl) and year can act discontinuously (end of heating season isn't the same as start of cooling).  Decent stats on the data say there are 5 seasons, not 4.  May is its own season, at least within the last 5 years.

Comment: @EngrStudent All good points and much appreciated.  I would maintain that the approach presented here, although simplified, shows what is needed to lay a foundation to tease out these subtler effects.  Once you handle the big terms in the model--and I think nobody will deny that temperature has to be a dominant contributor to costs--then, *if you have done that in a physically meaningful way,* you might be able to identify other terms and perhaps even estimate their effects accurately. If you don't deal with the big terms correctly, then you haven't any hope of characterizing the others.

Comment: I love this good foundation/analysis, please hear this as applause, not criticism.  The heating process is different than cooling, so the non-piecewise quadratic on both sides might be at odds with that.  The evaporator coil is indoors during cooling and outdoors during heating.  In heat-pump there is also defrost cycling and "back up heat".  Also, the compressor has to work harder to fight against a more extreme outdoor temperature, so not only are you moving more heat, you are moving it up a higher hill.  It isn't linear.  Humidity is big, and can be 2/3 the energy budget. Air infiltration.

Comment: @EngrStudent Thank you again--those are all interesting points.  I had no idea that humidity might account for such a large proportion of the budget.  That's the kind of observation that exemplifies the potential value of coupling a good theory (or "conceptual model" in some circles) with the statistical analysis.

Comment: A theorist will look at vapor-compression cooling on a psychrometric chart and assume that the liquid condensate is at the temperature where it condensed, but it is typically a few degrees below the lowest coil temperature.  Cooling that much liquid by that much is a sink.  Inefficiency/entropy.  Infiltration/leaks (such as people walking in the door) can be big. There are requirements about how frequently the air in the conditioned space is fully replaced by outside air.  In a place like Houston, a proposition like that means you have a constant inflow of humidity with your warm N2+oxygen.

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer over at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777890/data-visualization-how-to-represent-kwh-usage-by-year-against-average-temperatu).  If anyone has additional thoughts, I am still very interested in alternative solutions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777890/data-visualization-how-to-represent-kwh-usage-by-year-against-average-temperatu

Comment: The solution on SO is implausible. [Newton's law of cooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convective_heat_transfer#Newton.27s_law_of_cooling), which is a reasonable first-order approximation useful as a point of departure, suggests the plot of energy usage vs. temperature should be the union of two lines (perhaps of different slopes).  The average hides daily (and even hourly) temperature swings which will blur the region at the intersection of those lines (where neither heating nor cooling are needed). A quadratic fit might be reasonable there, but *asymptotically the fit needs to be linear*.

Comment: I know averages blur accuracy but its the data I have.  Due to poor understanding of statistics I fail to grasp phrases _"should be the union of two lines..."_ and _"asymptotically the fit needs to be linear"_.  From a novice POV, the SO post seems intuitive as it fits my expectation that energy consumption increase at opposite ends of temperature scale while being lowest in mid-range where neither heating nor cooling were needed. Wouldn't a quadratic fit be symmetrical? I dont believe power usage is symmetrical as we use more power to heat than cool. I appreciate any corrections or advice.

Comment: A quadratic fit, although symmetrical, is non-physical at the extremes, because it says you will pay much more for heating at the lowest temperatures, and much more for cooling at the highest temperatures, than is physically plausible. Moreover, symmetry in the plot would be expected only when the cost to cool the house per degree is the same as the cost to heat it per degree, which assumes the heating and cooling systems are equally efficient. That might or might not be the case--but you shouldn't impose that symmetry on your model.

Comment: I agree it differs as it costs more to cool than heat per degree.  However, so I understand the first comment, are you suggesting the quadratic fit from the SO post -- although reasonable -- is not truly accurate and that a linear fit is the technically correct answer due to Newtons's law of cooling?  It is the _implausibility of the SO solution_ that I am failing to understand.

Comment: I couldn't quite fit my response to that last question in the space for a comment, so I posted it as an answer instead. I don't see how you infer that per-degree cooling costs are greater than per-degree heating costs, though. Your data seem to indicate the opposite is true (although the costs are pretty close, as one would expect). And please note that a *linear model* does not imply a linear *fit*! There's a lot going on here to cause the data to deviate systematically from this underlying model.