# U shaped data in Simple linear regression

Tags: regression, data-transformation, linear

I am working on an analysis of a simple linear regression and I don't know what to do. This is my graph:
[image]

the p-value is <0.0001 but the data is clearly not linear and $R^2$ value is really small. What do you do in this situation? Transform it? Leave it as it is?

Comment: What does the plot show? What is on the $y$-axis? What exactly is your model?

Comment: Nothing to transform. Use splines or local polynomial or fractional polynomial to match the turning point. This looks like two effects, but they are not symmetric: temperature rising means more work in air conditioning; temperature falling means more work in heating. Good scientific manners to state units of measurement (temperature in Fahrenheit; no idea about vertical axis).

Comment: You should use piecewise linear function to do this. [Piecewise linear regression in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49907309/1876887)

Comment: The plot is strongly reminiscent of data about energy usage vs. temperature I analyzed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148166/919.  Regardless, the same principles I advocated there will serve you well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The p-value only tells you that the linear model is significantly better than a constant model.

The plot looks like a second-degree polynomial could fit well, i.e.

$$y=\beta_1 x^2 + \beta_2 x+\beta_3$$

This is linear - all you need to do is add a polynomial term to your predictors (i.e. create a new predictor $\mathrm{Temperature}^2$)

In R you can automagically do this with the formula interface: `y ~ poly(x, 2)`